# Mail Merging in ASP (vb.net) with multiple records

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mailmerge, docx-mailmerge

could anyone please help me how to implement mail merging with multiple records, I have tried `<<NEXT>>` in my .dot file but it did'nt work at all , 
.....

Comment: Are you using COM Automation, the official DOCX library, a third-party library, or something else? Note that COM Automation is not supported within ASP.NET due to COM permissions and concurrency issues.

Comment: Also you tagged this question with DOCX but you said you have a DOT file. The OOXML files are very different to the 97-2003 binary formats.

Comment: Ok, i picked up the project from someone else(who is not available anymore) , so how can I know which I am using, COM or a third-party library ? (Sorry, I am just new to this feature, ThankYou).

Comment: @Dai Ok, I am using Aspose.